# Laravel SimplePie как получить Json

Tags: laravel, rss, feed

Воспользовался RSS feed reader https://github.com/vedmant/laravel-feed-reader для получения SimplePie объекта.

```
$feed = FeedReader::read('https://www.examole.net/jobs/rss/');
 return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $feed
        ], 200);
```

Получаю на выходе большой json с кучей ненужных данных. А мне нужно вывести например `items`.

```
$feed->get_items();
```

Это массив объектов `SimplePie_Item`
Как правильно распарсить это в json?
Нужно подключать дополнительную библиотеку или что-то упустил?

Comment: http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/get_items

Comment: Мне нужен готовый json с бека. Впрочем не нашел метода, делал его вручную